# Inverse Association Rules

Tags: associations, rules, inverse

Association rules are a very common technique when you want to figure out which events happens together (like burger and bread mostly sell together). In marketing this technique is used to find out the complimentary products.

I am looking for a technique to extract the "Substitute Products" and to be it is like Inverse Association rules to find out which events are less likely happens together. Is there any algorithm or technique available in Spark, R, Python, etc. for this?

Thanks,
Amir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done an a very practical implementation for Substitution Rule Mining using [Teng, Hsieh and Chen (2002)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279125220_On_the_mining_of_substitution_rules_for_statistically_dependent_items) for R. Maybe it can help you:

```
# Used packages:
library(arules)


SRM <- function(TransData, MinSup, MinConf, pMin, pChi, itemLabel, nTID){

# Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------

if (sum(search() %in% "package:arules") == 0) {
stop("Please load package arules")
}  

# Checking Input data -----------------------------------------------------
 if (missing(TransData)) {
  stop("Transaction data is missing")
}

if (is.numeric(nTID) == FALSE) {
  stop("nTID has to be one numeric number for the count of      
 Transactions")
 }

  if (length(nTID) > 1) {
   stop("nTID has to be one number for the count of Transactions")
  }

  if (is.character(itemLabel) == FALSE) {
   stop("itemLabel has to be a character")
  }
  # Concrete Item sets  ---------------------------------------------------

  # adding complements to transaction data
  compl_trans <- addComplement(TransData,labels = itemLabel)
  compl_tab <- crossTable(compl_trans,"support")
  compl_tab_D <- as.data.frame(compl_tab)
  # ordering matrix
  compl_tab_D <-           compl_tab_D[order(rownames((compl_tab))),order(colnames((compl_tab)))]


  # Chi Value ---------------------------------------------------------------


  # empty data frame for loop

  complement_data <- data.frame(Chi = as.numeric(),
                           Sup_X.Y = as.numeric(),
                           X = as.character(),
                           Sup_X = as.numeric(),
                           Y = as.character(),
                           Sup_Y = as.numeric(),
                           CX = as.character(),
                           SupCX = as.numeric(),
                           CY = as.character(),
                           Sup_CY = as.numeric(),
                           Conf_X.CY = as.numeric(),
                           Sup_X.CY = as.numeric(),
                           Conf_Y.CX = as.numeric(),
                           SupY_CX = as.numeric())



  # first loop for one item
  for ( i in 1 : (length(itemLabel) - 1)) {
   # second loop combines it with all other items
   for (u in (i + 1) : length(itemLabel)) {


    # getting chi value from Teng
    a <-  itemLabel[i]
    b <-  itemLabel[u]
    ca <- paste0("!", itemLabel[i])
    cb <- paste0("!", itemLabel[u])

    chiValue <- nTID * (
     compl_tab[ca, cb] ^ 2 / (compl_tab[ca, ca] * compl_tab[cb, cb]) +
      compl_tab[ca, b] ^ 2 / (compl_tab[ca, ca] * compl_tab[b, b]) +
      compl_tab[a, cb] ^ 2 / (compl_tab[a, a] * compl_tab[cb, cb]) +
      compl_tab[a, b] ^ 2 / (compl_tab[a, a] * compl_tab[b, b]) - 1)



    # condition to be dependent
    if (compl_tab[a, b] > compl_tab[a, a] * compl_tab[b, b] &&      chiValue >= qchisq(pChi, 1) && 
        compl_tab[a, a] >= MinSup && compl_tab[b, b] >= MinSup ) {



     chi_sup <- data.frame(Chi = chiValue,
                      Sup_X.Y = compl_tab[a, b],
                      X = a,
                      Sup_X = compl_tab[a, a],
                      Y = b,
                      Sup_Y = compl_tab[b, b],
                      CX = ca,
                      SupCX = compl_tab[ca, ca],
                      CY = cb,
                      Sup_CY = compl_tab[cb, cb],
                      Conf_X.CY = compl_tab[a, cb] / compl_tab[a, a],
                      Sup_X.CY = compl_tab[a, cb],
                      Conf_Y.CX = compl_tab[ca, b] / compl_tab[b, b],
                      SupY_CX = compl_tab[ca, b])


     try(complement_data <- rbind(complement_data, chi_sup))

    }


   }
  }
  if (nrow(complement_data) == 0) {
   stop("No complement item sets could have been found")
  }


  #  changing mode of 
  complement_data$X <- as.character(complement_data$X)
  complement_data$Y <- as.character(complement_data$Y)


  # calculating support for concrete itemsets with all others and their complements -------------------


  ## with complements
  matrix_trans <- as.data.frame(as(compl_trans, "matrix"))

  sup_three <- data.frame(Items = as.character(),
                     Support = as.numeric()) 


  setCompl <- names(matrix_trans)
  # 1. extracts all other values than that are not in the itemset
  for (i in 1 : nrow(complement_data)) {
   value <- setCompl[ !setCompl %in% c(complement_data$X[i], 
                                  complement_data$Y[i], 
                                  paste0("!", complement_data$X[i]), 
                                  paste0("!",complement_data$Y[i]))]


   # 2. calculation of support
   for (u in value) {
    count <- sum(rowSums(matrix_trans[, c(complement_data$X[i],      complement_data$Y[i], u )]) == 3)
    sup <- count / nTID  
    sup_three_items <- data.frame(Items =      paste0(complement_data$X[i], complement_data$Y[i], u),
                             Support=sup) 
    sup_three <- rbind(sup_three, sup_three_items)
   }

  }

  # Correlation of single items-------------------------------------------------------------


  # all items of concrete itemsets should be mixed for correlation
  combis <- unique(c(complement_data$X, complement_data$Y))

  # empty object
  rules<- data.frame(
   Substitute = as.character(),
   Product = as.character(),
   Support = as.numeric(),
   Confidence = as.numeric(),
   Correlation = as.numeric())

  # first loop for one item
  for (i in 1 : (length(combis) - 1)) {
   # second loop combines it with all other items
   for (u in (i + 1) : length(combis)) {

    first <- combis[i]
    second <- combis[u]

    corXY <- (compl_tab[first, second] - (compl_tab[first, first] *      compl_tab[second, second])) /
(sqrt((compl_tab[first, first] * (1 - compl_tab[first,first])) *
       (compl_tab[second, second] * (1 - compl_tab[second, second]))))


    # confidence
    conf1 <- compl_tab[first, paste0("!", second)] / compl_tab[first, first]
    conf2 <- compl_tab[second, paste0("!", first)] / compl_tab[second, second]

    two_rules <- data.frame(
     Substitute = c(paste("{", first, "}"), 
               paste("{", second, "}")),
     Product = c(paste("=>", "{", second, "}"),
            paste("=>", "{", first, "}")),
     Support = c(compl_tab[first, paste0("!", second)], compl_tab[second, paste0("!", first)]),
     Confidence = c(conf1, conf2),
     Correlation = c(corXY, corXY)
    )

    # conditions
    try({
     if (two_rules$Correlation[1] < pMin) {
      if (two_rules$Support[1] >= MinSup && two_rules$Confidence[1] >= MinConf) {
       rules <- rbind(rules, two_rules[1, ])
 }
      if (two_rules$Support[2] >= MinSup && two_rules$Confidence[2] >= MinConf) {
       rules <- rbind(rules, two_rules[2, ])
      }

     } })

   }
  }


  # Correlation of concrete item pairs with single items --------------------
  # adding variable for loop
  complement_data$XY <- paste0(complement_data$X, complement_data$Y)

  # combination of items
  for (i in 1 : nrow(complement_data)){

   # set of combinations from dependent items with single items
   univector <- c(as.vector(unique(complement_data$X)),      as.vector(unique(complement_data$Y)))
   univector <- univector[!univector %in% c(complement_data$X[i], complement_data$Y[i])]

   combis <- c(complement_data[i,"XY"], univector)



   for (u in 2 : length(combis)) {
    corXYZ <-(sup_three[sup_three$Items == paste0(combis[1], combis[u]),2] - 
               complement_data[complement_data$XY == combis[1],"Sup_X.Y"] *
          compl_tab[combis[u],combis[u]]) /
(sqrt((complement_data[complement_data$XY == combis[1],"Sup_X.Y"] * 
         (1 - complement_data[complement_data$XY == combis[1],"Sup_X.Y"]) *
        compl_tab[combis[u],combis[u]] * (1 - compl_tab[combis[u],combis[u]]))))

    dataXYZ <- data.frame(
Substitute = paste("{", combis[1], "}"), 
Product = paste("=>", "{", combis[u], "}"),
Support = sup_three[sup_three$Items == paste0(combis[1], "!", combis[u]),2],
Confidence = sup_three[sup_three$Items == paste0(combis[1], "!", combis[u]),2] /
 complement_data[complement_data$XY == combis[1],"Sup_X.Y"],
Correlation = corXYZ)


    # conditions
    if (dataXYZ$Correlation < pMin && dataXYZ$Support >= MinSup && dataXYZ$Confidence >= MinConf) {

     try(rules <- rbind(rules, dataXYZ))
    }
   }
  }
  if (nrow(rules) == 0) {
   message("Sorry no rules could have been calculated. Maybe change input conditions.")
  }      else {
   return(rules)
  }

  # end
 }
```

I think a better explanation is in my blog:
http://mattimeyer.github.io/2016-12-21-Substitution-Rule-Mining/